Is it possible to add event listener to dependent field in form?
In Symfony, it's possible to add event listener on form field and then process the live value. This works perfectly, even in array of collections in form.
On the other hand, I've got dependent field in the form
https://ux.symfony.com/demos/live-component/dependent-form-fields (values of dependent choice depends on value from other choice, which is dependency
If I try to add event listener on this dependent field:
->addDependent('customerId', 'company', function (DependentField $field, ?Companies $company) {
->get('customerId')->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, $customerIdListener);
I get error:
Error rendering "purchase_form" component: The child with the name "customerId" does not exist.
Is it possible to work with dependent fields in this way? Many thanks
